# Subset sum implementation

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am implementing the algorithm for subset sum :

```
SUBSET SUM(X[1 .. n], T ):
if T = 0
return T RUE
else if T < 0 or n = 0
return FALSE
else
return SUBSET SUM(X[2 .. n], T ) ∨ SUBSET SUM(X[2 .. n], T − X[1])
```

Please help me out in how can I pass the reduced array X[2...n] when recursing ?

This is the code I wrote and it causes a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int subsetsum(int a[], int sum, int size)
    {
            if(sum==0)
            return 1;
            else if (sum<0 || size <0)
            return  0;
            else
            return (subsetsum(a+1 , sum, size-1) || subsetsum(a+1, sum - *a, size-1));
    }
    `

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
            int a[]={2,4,1,3,5},x;
            x=subsetsum(a,6,5);
            printf("%d",x);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you wrote so far and where exactly are you stuck.

Comment: Here is the code : 
http://pastebin.com/mxg97e4x
Gives segmentation fault.

Comment: C or C++. Choose. Decide. Prosper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array's in C/C++ are implicitly decayed into pointers to the original memory buffer representing the array when used as arguments to functions.  So in order to pass `X[2...n]`, you simply can increment the array pointer argument by `1`.  For instance, you could do something like the following:

```
bool subset_sum(const int* array, const int array_size, int* sum)
{
    //...your code for the rest of the algorithm

    subset_sum(array+1, array_size, sum) //one of the recursive calls
}
```

Passing the argument `array+1` on the next recursive call will increment the array pointer by one, and take a pointer pointing to the array `X[1...n]` and now make it point to the array `X[2...n]`.  You would use the `array_size` argument to detect the end of the array.

Finally, you would call `subset_sum` like so:

```
int array_numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int sum = 0;

subset_sum(array_numbers, sizeof(array_numbers)/sizeof(int), &sum);
```

Comment: change `else if (sum<0 || size <0)` to `else if (sum < 0 || size == 0)`

Comment: BTW, there is no need to check if size is less-than-or-equal to zero ... if size ever got to be less-than zero, you have a big-problem ... by mathematical induction, it should never reach that point.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class It>
void recurse(It begin, It end)
{
   ... recurse(begin+1, end) ...
}
```